# Passing an integer array to mysql procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, stored-procedures, integer

I want to create a stored procedure which receives array of integers and some other input, for example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test (field1 varchar(4), field2 varchar(4), array varchar (255))
```

and in the stored procedure I want to use it like this:

```
...
WHERE some_field IN (array)
...
```

The problem is that in this way I am getting only the rows which correspondence to the first integer in the array.

Is there any way to make it work (I also tried to use `FIND_IN_SET` but it did exactly the same as `IN`)?

The call that I am making for testing the stored procedure is `CALL test (12, 13, '1, 2, 3')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FIND_IN_SET() works, but you can't have spaces in the string of numbers.

Demo:

```
mysql> select find_in_set(2, '1, 2, 3');
+---------------------------+
| find_in_set(2, '1, 2, 3') |
+---------------------------+
|                         0 |
+---------------------------+

mysql> select find_in_set(2, '1,2,3');
+-------------------------+
| find_in_set(2, '1,2,3') |
+-------------------------+
|                       2 |
+-------------------------+
```

So you should either form the list with no spaces before you pass it to your procedure, or else in the procedure, use REPLACE() to strip out spaces.

Answer (score 0):

There no array concept. So what you can do probably is like

Your `array` variable has values `'1, 2, 3'` as string

1. split the string with `,` as delimiter which will
2. insert each value to a temporary table

so your temp table will have `1,2,3`

Finally just use your temp table like

> ```
>  WHERE some_field IN (select array_id from temp_table)
> ```